# Modify r.horizon script in PyQGIS to process each output raster after the other and save it and not waiting to the end

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-processing, google-colab

I installed QGIS on Google Colab and run this code first for small sample in order to check that it works there, it is perfect!

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingFeedback
import processing 

class MyFeedBack(QgsProcessingFeedback):
    def pushCommandInfo(self, info):
        print(info)

processing.run("grass7:r.horizon", 
    {'elevation':'DEM.tif',
    'direction':None,
    'step':90,'start':0,'end':360,
    'bufferzone':None,
    'e_buff':None,'w_buff':None,'n_buff':None,'s_buff':None,
    'maxdistance':None,
    'distance':1,
    '-d':True,'-c':True,
    'output':'/content/drive/MyDrive/result',
    'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,
    'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0
    },
    feedback =MyFeedBack()
)
```

I would to run this `r.horizon` algorithm to a larger rasters, It worked also but the problem is as following:

Sometimes Google Colab disconnects or something goes wrong so all the temporary files of that algorithm are lost before it finishes them then saves them to the destination directory `/content/drive/MyDrive/result` permanently.

I run this algorithm on simple small raster in order to understand its logic, I noticed the following things:

1- It creates many temporary folders and files in `/tmp` so all those files here will be lost if something goes wrong with Google Colab.

2- For the algorithm above, it should output 4 horizon rasters, one each 90 degrees, it does that indeed but the algorithm waits untill all steps are complete then it processes and finishes them to the destination.

Is there some methods to modify this algorithm, process each raster and finalize it after each step then save it to destination in order to secure it, so decreasing lost data if something happens?

I tried once and manually to download them from `/tmp` one after eachother when it comes (Not nice work and need long time) but I inspected those rasters especially in the directory `fcell`, even though those files have no extension, I thought, they would be `.tif`, so I renamed one of them as `.tif` and tried to open it in QGIS app, it is invalid, then I inspected its magic number, it is definetely no `.tif` raster.

So this approach to download them manually also failed, now still the hope to change something in the algorithm.

That is the tree created by this algorithm, for my case, 4 outputs:

```
Temp
  └── processing_RbNTJx
      ├── a27996d6592048279fe318988768dd8a
      │   └── crs.prj
      └── grassdata
          ├── grass_batch_job.cmd
          └── temp_location
              └── PERMANENT
                  ├── DEFAULT_WIND
                  ├── MYNAME
                  ├── PROJ_EPSG
                  ├── PROJ_INFO
                  ├── PROJ_SRID
                  ├── PROJ_UNITS
                  ├── PROJ_WKT
                  ├── VAR
                  ├── WIND
                  ├── cats
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_000
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_090
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_180
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_270
                  │   └── rast_65d8e28897e8f17
                  ├── cell
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_000
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_090
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_180
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_270
                  │   └── rast_65d8e28897e8f17
                  ├── cell_misc
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_000
                  │   │   ├── f_format
                  │   │   ├── f_quant
                  │   │   ├── f_range
                  │   │   ├── nullcmpr
                  │   │   ├── stats
                  │   │   └── units
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_090
                  │   │   ├── f_format
                  │   │   ├── f_quant
                  │   │   ├── f_range
                  │   │   ├── nullcmpr
                  │   │   ├── stats
                  │   │   └── units
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_180
                  │   │   ├── f_format
                  │   │   ├── f_quant
                  │   │   ├── f_range
                  │   │   ├── nullcmpr
                  │   │   ├── stats
                  │   │   └── units
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_270
                  │   │   ├── f_format
                  │   │   ├── f_quant
                  │   │   ├── f_range
                  │   │   ├── nullcmpr
                  │   │   ├── stats
                  │   │   └── units
                  │   └── rast_65d8e28897e8f17
                  │       ├── nullcmpr
                  │       ├── range
                  │       └── stats
                  ├── cellhd
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_000
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_090
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_180
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_270
                  │   └── rast_65d8e28897e8f17
                  ├── fcell
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_000
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_090
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_180
                  │   └── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_270
                  ├── hist
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_000
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_090
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_180
                  │   ├── outputcfc2f382127a4715ba0947682238111b_270
                  │   └── rast_65d8e28897e8f17
                  └── sqlite
```